# Setting Pointers to 2d Array equal - Invalid array assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a pointer to 2d array of qint8: `qint8 *data[200][8];`

I want to pass that pointer to another class in the constructor:

SomeClass.h also has `qint8 *data[200][8];`

SomeClass.cpp:

```
SomeClass::TilesetBehaviorsView(QWidget *parent, qint8 *behaviors[200][8]) ::QWidget(parent)
{
    *this->items = *items;
}
```

I get this error message:

```
E:\Learning\Cpp\MultidemensionalArrays\someclass.cpp:10: Error: invalid array assignment
 *this->data = *data;
             ^
```

Comment: Try removing both the asterisks

Comment: Then I get: Error: incompatible types in assignment of 'qint8* (*)[8] {aka signed char* (*)[8]}' to 'qint8* [200][8] {aka signed char* [200][8]}'
     this->data = data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a pointer to 2d array of `qint8`: `qint8 *data[200][8];`

No. You have a 2D array of pointers to `qint8`. If you really want a pointer to array, you'd have to declare it like this:

```
qint8 (*data)[200][8];
```

However, pointers to arrays are generally not very useful in C++. You have to use parentheses to access their members, for example:

```
qint8 a = (*data)[4][2];
```

With C++11, there's hardly ever need for C-style arrays anyway. Use `std::array` instead, which doesn't have all these issues with priority, decay, or non-assignability:

```
std::array<std::array<qint8, 8>, 200> data;
```

Or, given the size of the whole data structure, consider using dynamic arrays (`std::vector`).